# Code coloring for PowerShell

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting, languages

See for example this question related to PowerShell: *https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28311739/powershell-getting-the-string-value-of-variable-manipulating-variable*

[image: Actual]

And this is how I see it in PowerShell ISE:

[image]

So I guess I'm saying... some color formatting would be nice :)

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362286/enable-a-lang-powershell-option-for-prettify-on-stack-overflow, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295730/enable-automatic-syntax-highlighting-of-powershell

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can actually get syntax coloring for PowerShell if you add this line before your code:

`<!-- language-all: lang-powershell -->`

Demo:

```powershell
$include = @("*.csv", "*.txt","*.dat")
$oldday = (Get-Date).AddDays(-2)
$path = "C:\TESTING\tester\test1\testfiles"

$Allfiles = Get-Childitem -Path $path -include $include -recurse| Where {!$_.PSIsContainer -and ($_.CreationTime -gt $oldday)} | Select-Object Fullname

foreach ($file in $Allfiles)
    {
       $file1 = $file.Fullname
       $foldername = Get-ChildItem -Path $file.Fullname
       $input = $foldername.Directoryname
       $Mothername = Get-Item -Path $input
       $output = $Mothername.Parent.Fullname
       $output = "$output\sc"
       Write-Host "The Filename: $file1"
       Write-Host "The FolderName: $input"
       Write-Host "$output"
       $argument = "$input $output $input"
    }
```

For more information, see *[What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work)*.

Comment: Why isn't this done automatically? This would force me to edit the questions to make them readable...

Comment: Well, the [powershell] tag isn't very popular (just 22,000 questions compared to the hundreds of thousands in tags like [java] or [c#]).  SO simply hasn't added support for it to be automatically enabled yet.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels what a ridiculous argument... all I'm saying is, if the other languages have automatic coloring, why doesn't PowerShell?

Comment: @I19: Because no mod has stumbled over the need yet, nor been asked for it. Your question now will probably get one to take action.

Comment: Perhaps worth noting is use of `<!-- language: lang-none -->` after the code block in question, e.g. if some output or error message is formatted with four leading spaces.

Comment: All this is doing is making things that are capitalized in blue and quotes are in red.  It only highlights "get" if it was small letters.  It's better in github, with ```powershell at the start of the code, (which doesn't work here).

Comment: Powershell syntax highlighting in Stackoverflow is terrible.

Comment: The syntax highlighting in the demo doesn't look right for me

Comment: I would just use: 3 backticks as usual like `\`\`\`lang-powershell \n\n \`\`\`` ... instead of the html comment