# Enable automatic syntax highlighting of PowerShell

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

Recently, PowerShell syntax highlighting has become available in SE posts.

But one has to explicitly request that using

```
<!-- language: lang-powershell -->
```

It's not automatically used as with other languages.

Can I request that PowerShell syntax highlighting is automatically used for questions tagged [powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell)?

Comment: Unfortunately, as of late 2022, perhaps related to the switch from prettify.js to highlight.js, PowerShell syntax highlighting is broken again. Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421016/45375

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, `lang-powershell` does not event exist. It just triggers some kind of default syntax highlighting.

But so does [powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell) tag since recently. So my request is kind of implemented.

See for example:
[PowerShell FTP upload not working - Creating zero byte file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31528223/850848)

Comment: Looks like it defaults to `lang-bsh`... Doesn't appear to be a `lang-powershell` available from the default drop language drop down for tags... so not 100% sure this is *done* actually.

Comment: @JonClements OK, it seems that `lang-poweshell` is the same as `lang-bsh`. But it works reasonably well for PowerShell.

Comment: @JonClements What is "language drop down for tags"?

Comment: It's an option that mods can use to set default highlighting for tags...

Comment: As for `lang-powershell` - it appears to be still an open issue: https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/detail?id=295

Comment: @JonClements Well, I'm not sure how it works internally. But since recently PowerShell code is highlighted reasonably well when [tag:powershell] tag is used.

Comment: @JonClements You are right that `lang-powershell` indeed does not work, it just triggers some kind of default highlighting. The same what [tag:powershell] tag does.

Comment: If you give an invalid language `<!-- language: lang-whatever -->` it ignores it and will use the default associated with the "main" tag of the question - so `lang-bsh` in this case

Comment: But something had to change, as before (when asked this question), the mere presence of [tag:powershell] tag did not help. One had to specify (invalid) `lang-powershell`.  Anyway, I've updated my answer.

Comment: The current behavior is quite broken, especially with respect to escape characters. If a powershell question has a \" inside it, the engine never closes the quote making the entire script look busted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34661567/i-cannot-get-the-if-else-to-work-properly-with-my-powershell-script

Comment: @Eris That's true. I've seen this too.