# Batch syntax highlighting

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

While analyzing questions and answers in [batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/batch) I've noticed the difficulty of reading the code because it's just the plain black text on gray background. Similarly, [bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash) (unix/linux equivalent of batch) does have highlighting, so i see no reason why batch shouldn't.

Comment: Would you be happy with "lang-sh" highlighting like bash? Or which existing option works?

Comment: Yes, the lang-sh highlighting would work fine

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295730/enable-automatic-syntax-highlighting-of-powershell/