# Trailing backslash in strings breaks code formatting

Tags: bug, code-formatting, syntax-highlighting

I did not find an answer to this after searching a bit : **On stackoverflow.com, is there a way to avoid breaking a code block's formatting when including a string with a trailing backslash** ?

It's common on the Windows platform to use strings like `C:\Users\me\`.

If you include this in a code block along with more code, the following code is not syntax-highlighted properly (I guess it's because the last double-quote is escaped by the `\`?):

Note the formatting used for code in this question: `<!-- language-all: lang-powershell -->`

```powershell
$myPath = "C:\Users\me\"

$myFile = "whatever.txt"

Get-Item "$myPath$myFile"
```

The same snippet without the trailing backslash is parsed properly:

```powershell
$myPath = "C:\Users\me"

$myFile = "whatever.txt"

Get-Item "$myPath$myFile"
```

See an example in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34147673/it-sounds-complex-but-its-not-comparing-files-in-powershell) (from *Here is my code so far...*), everything after the first line of code is "messed up":

[image: example]

**EDIT** : FYI, escaping character in PS is the backtick `

Comment: Is the syntax legal in that language?

Comment: Yes, because the escaping character is the backtick ` in PowerShell

Comment: It defaults to display as lang-bsh and bash uses \ escapes

Comment: Yes... you found the problem. That one has been bugging me. @AlexK. I tried forcing the highlighting for lang-ps on the linked question but it didnt fix it. At least now I know what to do to make the highlighting work since removing the slash does not break the code in most cases.

Comment: powershell does not seem to be supported; https://github.com/google/code-prettify#for-which-languages-does-it-work

Comment: Related feature-req: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295730/enable-automatic-syntax-highlighting-of-powershell

Comment: Still unfixed more than five years later :-(

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The PowerShell tag is using lang-bsh as its prettifier.

[image: lang-bsh on the PowerShell tag]

There is an open issue over on [GitHub](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/issues/295) with an initial commit for a PowerShell prettifier. I linked to that item in an answer I wrote over on [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214234/158100).

Using the the C# prettifier gives a slightly better result although it struggles with that same backslash, but it seems to recover better from that mishap.

`<!-- language: lang-cs -->`

```cs
$strDir = "D:\Temp\FileCompareTest\"

$strFileTypesToIgnore = ".jkl",".mno"

$arrFiles = Get-ChildItem $strDir -exclude $strFileTypesToIgnore

ForEach ($objFile in $arrFiles) {
    $strFilename = $objFile.BaseName
}
```

Do note that Stack Exchange doesn't own the code for prettify. From the [FAQ at MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/158100):

> Stack Exchange does not have its own syntax highlighting engine. It uses Google Code Prettify. Therefore, any bugs and feature requests regarding syntax highlighting **cannot be handled by Stack Exchange** and should be directed to the team behind Google Code Prettify.

<sup>Emphasis is mine.</sup>

Comment: Thanks, `<!-- language: lang-cs -->` works better indeed. Hope this will be fixed someday :-).

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer to the highlighting issue but it is worth mentioning that removing the backslash is a good mean-time solution as it restores proper formatting and does not reduce the readability or functionality of code.

While not always read including a statement in the comment for the editing reason (assuming there is nothing else of merit to update) would be a good practice.

Also, Good catch!

Comment: If you concatenate strings to build paths, it makes a big difference. If you use `Join-Path` (in PowerShell at least), as you're kinda supposed to, it is the same, functionnality-wise.

Comment: @sodawillow oh... I have been down that path http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25880122/how-do-i-use-join-path-to-combine-more-than-two-strings-into-a-file-path/25880610#25880610. In _this_ case it should work fine removing it. Might just use cs formatting like rene says though.

Comment: I sometimes use a function that will add a slash to a directory string unless there's already one.  That helps to keep consistency because sometimes they will be supplied without the slash and sometimes with.