# Enable a "lang-powershell" option for Prettify on Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

I wrote an answer on Stack Overflow with some [PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) code examples, but there's no syntax highlighting. There are currently [29,611](//stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell) <sup>(as of 2015-12-08)</sup> questions tagged [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) on Stack Overflow. Please add prettified syntax highlighting to PowerShell questions.

These are the one's I experimented with in my original testing.

```
<!-- language: lang-ps-->
<!-- language: lang-ps1-->
<!-- language: lang-powershell-->
<!-- language: lang-posh-->
```

---

Side note: there are only [5,591](//stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dart) <sup>(as of 2015-12-08)</sup> questions tagged [dart](/questions/tagged/dart) on Stack Overflow, and it is [already supported](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/981/syntax-highlighting-language-hints/75019#75019)

---

*Close voters, please read my [comment below](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167612/there-needs-to-be-a-lang-powershell-option-for-prettify-on-so#comment579827_167612) before casting your vote. I believe Stack Overflow is maintaining their own version now, so forking the original and adding `posh` support would NOT solve this feature request.*

Comment: Last updated Aug 25 '11: [list of supported languages](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/981/syntax-highlighting-language-hints/75019#75019).

Comment: Doesn't seem that there is support for powershell.

Comment: You can try putting it through another syntax highlighter like Pygments and copying the HTML. I make no guarantee that the sanitizer will like the HTML that comes out though.

Comment: hmmm, @Linuxios, I'm not sure that will accomplish what I'm asking. This needs to be implemented on SO...

Comment: @nhahtdh, you appear to be right. I wonder how hard the additional implementation would be.

Comment: This should really be a feature request, it would dramatically improve readability on powershell questions

Comment: Not sure I like the cute shorthand like `ps` by itself - people may think it is PostScript, or PL/SQL, or PostgreSQL, who knows. `posh` would probably be less ambiguous and not really all that much more painful to write (especially since all the powershell-related tags should trigger that as the default formatting once it is implemented).

Comment: never thought of `posh`, but you're probably right.

Comment: trying to write this myself as per my question... lack of documentation on prettify itself is becoming a problem

Comment: I've done some format testing in the sandbox it would be plausible to use the `csh` highlighting until such a plugin was developed

Comment: I believe they're using Google Code Prettify, which isn't native to SE. You could try forking [the source](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) and adding support, then asking them to pull it back in.

Comment: You could be right, but I was under the impression that SE forked that long ago and are maintaining their own now.

Comment: There is an [open issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/detail?id=295) for Prettify that includes a language file for PowerShell. It’s incomplete but definitely better than no syntax highlighting at all (current situation). Can we reopen the question and get that language file added to the highlighter?

Comment: @poke I've voted to re-open - the issue tracker says "the only thing I know it has trouble with is delimited comments, which follow the pattern <# comment #>" which sounds a lot better than nothing.

Comment: How is this not implemented yet in 2018? PS has been around for almost 12 YEARS! It's pre-posh-terous (*lol*) that this hasn't been prettified yet! >.< ... and while `posh` is a fine shorthand, I think `psh` is in better keeping with existing shorthands like `csh` and `bsh`. PLEASE IMPLEMENT THIS!!! ;)

Comment: See the duplicate, specifically the *How do I report a bug or request a new language?* section.

Comment: For powershell, I would just use: 3 backticks as usual like `\`\`\`lang-powershell \n\n \`\`\`` ... as the tag `powershell` does not work, but `lang-*` reference uses the language directly

Comment: @BananaAcid this question was from 2013, a lot has changed.

Comment: For an updated feature request that accounts for the change from prettify.js to highlight.js, please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421016/45375

Answer (score 3):

Currently the best option I have found for PowerShell is CoffeeScript:

```
<!-- language: lang-coffee -->
```

However, this is not perfect as it missed some elements such as escaping strings, etc.

That said, you make some very excellent points @ChaseFlorell and I find it hard to believe that this still has not been implemented after 12 years of PowerShell. I guess for the time being we're stuck with Coffee... speaking of which... it's about that time. ;)

Comment: The order of things to happen is still that Prettify needs to support it first and based on [this open issue](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/issues/295) it looks like that is still in the works. You could help there to make a proper pull-request, adding docs and tests for that file in the attachtment. Once it is merged and part of an stable release of Prettify, SE can make a move to pull a newer release.

Comment: Excellent suggestion @rene. I shall look into that. ;)

Comment: `\`\`\`shell` also works okay, but I use `\`\`\`powershell` so it works correctly when they support it.

Comment: @rene, that GitHub repo has been archived by Google. Where's the current source of this js?

Comment: @JakeEdwards it is now HighlightJS, found [here](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/) and [here is the MSE canonical](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109)

Comment: @Chiramisu, for an updated feature request that accounts for the change from prettify.js to highlight.js, please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421016/45375