# Enable automatic and on-demand syntax highlighting for PowerShell (updated for highlight.js)

Tags: feature-request, status-review, syntax-highlighting, powershell, powershell-core

<sup>Note: After the discussion in the comments, a separate post was spun off from this one, linked to below.</sup>

Note:

- This isn't a duplicate of earlier posts such as [Enable a "lang-powershell" option for Prettify on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/362286/45375), because (a) they are obsolete due to referring to the *previous* highlighting library and (b) the problem persists.

Please fully support PowerShell syntax highlighting on all relevant SE sites:

- PowerShell, even though it is [supported by highlight.js *in principle*](https://highlightjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/supported-languages.html), is [*not* currently supported *on SE sites*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/248777) (section "Language codes currently available on Stack Exchange").

Note:

- I am aware that such a request is ["extremely likely to be considered low-priority"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/248777); the backstory is in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368443/248777).
- [Syntax highlighting: Use "lang-bash" (or similar) as default language for tags [powershell] and [powershell-core] until PowerShell is fully supported](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421022/45375) is a related request for an *interim, stopgap* solution in order to improve the current PowerShell highlighting experience, which can be implemented by simple moderator action.

<sup>Tip of the hat to [Henry Ecker](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/15497888/henry-ecker) and [Makyen](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3773011/makyen).</sup>

Comment: Slight nitpick, using `lang-powershell` is **not** a workaround for the problem. ["Just because you type something in and it looks like it's highlighted correctly does not mean the identifier actually exists in the system. Keep in mind that invalid identifiers trigger an automatic language detection."](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/1099857). For example, the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27768628/15497888) when annotated with `lang-powershell` defaults and highlights using `lang-php` [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tpX0.png)

Comment: Sorry I was unclear, the primary point is even though you can type `lang-powershell` it falls back to "automatic language detection" meaning there is no guarantee what highlighting will be used. More examples from the same question: the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27771099/15497888) is highlighted with `lang-less`, the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68746157/15497888) is highlighted with `lang-python`. The code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56288586/15497888) is `lang-bash` and `lang-delphi` regardless of if the block is annotated with `lang-powershell`.

Comment: Letting highlight.js choose what highlighting to use does give _some_ highlighting that may or may not look OK, but there's no difference currently between writing `lang-powershell` and not annotating anything.

Comment: Your statement "please associate these tags with `lang-powershell`, which can be done NOW" is false. That can **not** be done *at this time* (note: changing the language listed for a tag is a request for moderator action, not SE). PowerShell is not a supported highlighting language. Even if it was, it would need to be added to the list of selectable languages on tag pages (which list is a subset of those supported and the values are verified in SE's backend, so we, moderators, can't just add them).

Comment: Basically, there are two parts to actions which could be taken. 1) There's SE actually supporting it, which requires A) that highlight.js support the language and B) SE choosing to include the language in those which they support (don't get me started on this one, as there's lot's of frustration with the issues which go back to a poor implementation architecture); and 2) there's selecting the language which will be used for the tag, which can be from a limited list (again, lots of frustration going back to SE's implementation/architecture).

Comment: What can be done *now* is assign a default syntax highlighting language for the tags. There's lots of trade-offs in doing so. Unless there's a supported syntax highlighting language which gets fairly close, then the best choice is *often* "none", because the auto-selection when there's any combination of tags with different assigned highlighting languages, due to choices SE's made (which causes "default" to be used under way to many circumstances), is commonly fubared (i.e. it's SE's fault, not highlight.js).

Comment: So, for what can be done *now*, a choice needs to be selected from bad options. This is usually means weighing the possibilities and selecting the *least bad* option as applied across the 100k affected questions. This is a frustrating process and is made more so, because SE doesn't do the right thing when the combination of tags on a question apply more than one syntax highlighting language. So, the information which moderators need to adjust the tag's implied highlighting language is if there's one that's on the available list which looks notably better than nothing under most circumstances.

Comment: Thanks, @Makyen. A) is already met, as stated in the post. B) is one part of what the question requests. I understand that this a big ask, and is considered low-priority. While "none" would be _better_ than the current behavior, `lang-php` or `lang-bash` strike me as the superior, passable alternatives.

Comment: Note: SE's effective response to *any* request for supporting a new syntax highlighting language is in [answer to: "Julia syntax highlighting"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368443/271271) to which it's been suggested moderators point people. Basically it's, at best, 6–8.

Comment: It's possible (probably even common/normal, given most people making requests know something isn't working right, but don't know the details of the current system) to have both in a single question. My *personal* preference is two questions: A) one for changing the assigned language for the tag now (which can be a [meta-tag:support] and be acted upon by a moderator resulting in a [meta-tag:status-completed]); and another question, B) as a [meta-tag:feature-request], for the longer-term request of asking for full support (which can get a [tag:status-review] to put it into SE ticketing system).

Comment: Related/of interest: "[Stop guessing/auto-detecting a language when you KNOW it will be incorrect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/355852/271271)"

Comment: Thanks, @Makyen, I've kept this post as the official feature request for proper PowerShell support and have broken out the stopgap solution into a separate post, [Syntax highlighting: Use "lang-bash" (or similar) as default language for tags \[powershell\] and \[powershell-core\] until PowerShell is fully supported](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421022/45375). Is it OK to keep both on Meta _SO_ or should I post them on Meta _SE_ instead or can you migrate them, if appropriate?

Comment: @Makyen, based on your recommendation to use a [tag:support]-tagged post for assigning a code language, it's worth updating https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/248777, which currently states (emphasis added): "If the tag doesn't have a highlighting language specified when it should, create a **feature-request** on your site's per-site meta to request it". Let me ask again, to be sure: That _this_ post - requesting proper PowerShell support - is on Meta _SO_ is fine, even though the linked post says to use Meta _SE_? Or should I repost / can you migrate?

Comment: As to [meta-tag:feature-request] vs. [meta-tag:support] for the request to change the assigned syntax highlighting language for a tag, I could argue either way, but FR is probably more canonical, because it is actually asking for a change. With respect to the request for full language support being on MSO vs. MSE, I don't believe it really matters all that much. As long as it gets a [meta-tag:status-review] it goes into SE's tracking system. On MSE, it may or may not be seen by people from multiple sites, have a higher score, and, thus, appear to have more support (I've seen it go both ways).

Comment: Thanks, @Makyen, I think I'll leave it here, as I'd expect SO users to care most. As for "support" vs. "feature-request": my understanding of your earlier comment was that I should use _just_ "support" for the post requesting the simple code-language assignment change. Are you saying I should use _both_ tags? (I've just added "feature-quest" to [Syntax highlighting: Use "lang-bash" (or similar) as default language for tags \[powershell\] and \[powershell-core\] until PowerShell is fully supported](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421022/45375), to be safe.)