# Syntax highlighting: Use "lang-bash" (or similar) as default language for tags [powershell] and [powershell-core] until PowerShell is fully supported

Tags: support, feature-request, syntax-highlighting, powershell, powershell-core

Note:

- There are related existing posts, but this one makes a concrete proposal that complements the feature-request post that asks for *proper* PowerShell syntax-highlighting support via highlight.js, [Enable automatic and on-demand syntax highlighting for PowerShell (updated for highlight.js)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421016/45375)

Currently, the tags [powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell) and [powershell-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell-core) are  associated with SE's [*default* highlighting behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/powershell/info) and with [none at all](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/powershell-core/info), respectively.
This **currently often results in *completely broken* highlighting**, as the language used for highlighting is then inferred from the *other* tags that a given post is tagged with, and if there is only *one* other tag for which a highlighting language is configured, *that* language is used for all code blocks; for instance, a post tagged with both [xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xml) and [powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell) will currently cause any PowerShell code to be uselessly and distractingly formatted *as XML*.

That problem will *situationally* go away once PowerShell syntax highlighting is fully supported, as requested in the linked post, but for the reasons discussed there, such requests are considered both low-priority and high-impact, so their implementation may be far off or, God forbid, may never happen at all.
As Andrew T. notes in a comment, this will *not necessarily* provide the proper highlighting *automatically*, given that if a question post has *multiple* tags *that have highlighting languages assigned*, it is *automatic detection* that kicks in, per code block,<sup>[1]</sup> which may or may not identify the code correctly. This is a *general* problem on SE, however; at a minimum, proper support will simplify providing *manual*  highlighting hints, based on the `powershell` *tag*, such as ```` ```powershell ```` and `<!-- language-all: powershell -->`

Thus, **this request is for a *pragmatic stopgap* that *can be implemented right now* and would significantly improve the current experience**.

- **Make `lang-bash` the default code language for [powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell) and [powershell-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell-core) FOR NOW**, as long as proper PowerShell support isn't yet implemented:

  - Clearly, Bash is different from PowerShell, but the syntax is, at least in parts, similar enough to make for a *passable* highlighting experience that is superior to having *none* (see below).
  - (If someone can come up with a better fit, all the better; `lang-php` appears to work similarly well / poorly.)
  - See the bottom section for examples and limitations of rendering PowerShell code with `lang-bash`.
- The alternative - undesirable to my mind, but still an improvement over the current situation - is to *disable* highlighting altogether, i.e. to associate the tags with
  `lang-none`

  - More generally, it would make sense for *all* tags relating to languages for which no highlighter is currently available to *default* to `lang-none`, as suggested in [Stop guessing/auto-detecting a language when you KNOW it will be incorrect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/355852/271271)

---

**Workarounds for now**:

To get a (somewhat) predictable, (mostly) useful highlighting PowerShell experience **for now**,
individual code blocks - or whole posts, via a HTML comment - **must be *explicitly* marked as using a specific highlighter**, and there are two basic options:

- **Option A:** Use ```` ```lang-powershell ```` or `<!-- language-all: lang-powershell -->`, even though the `lang-powershell` highlight.js identifier isn't yet officially supported.

  - The upside is that posts tagged this way *could* benefit from *proper* highlighting *if and when it becomes available* in the future, because `lang-powershell` should be a supported identifier then (see [the list of supported languages in the highlight.js docs and their identifiers](https://highlightjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/supported-languages.html) and how the map onto [the `lang-`-prefixed identifiers used on SE sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/248777) (section "Language codes currently available on Stack Exchange"), which are a *subset* of the languages that highlight.js supports.

    - That said, it seems that it takes at least a *dummy edit* to old posts in order to *re-render* them from the Markdown source based on the then-recognized languages.
  - For now, this *currently unknown* ID triggers *automatic language detection*, which is notably based on the *specific code*<sup>[2]</sup> (as opposed to the current behavior of letting *other tags* pick the language):

    - *Typically*, PowerShell code is automatically detected as either `language-bash` or `language-php`, which, as stated, makes for a *passable* experience now.
  - The downside is that the automatic detection may sometimes pick an *unhelpful* language. In that case you can use Option B.
- **Option B:** Tell a white lie and use `sh` (which maps onto `lang-bash`) instead - ```` ```sh ```` or `<!-- language-all: sh -->`

  - The upside is that you get `lang-bash` highlighting *predictably*, resulting in *passable* highlighting.
  - The downside is that you *lock in* that so-so highlighting, without automatically benefitting from proper highlighting if and when it becomes available in the future. (You'd have to go back and edit old posts manually). Also, it may be bit confusing to see a reference to a *different* language in the source code - fortunately, however, that is invisible to the *readers* of a post.

---

**Examples of highlighting PowerShell code with `sh` == `lang-bash`:**

- What **works** (well enough - note that there's generally *little* coloring, but at least there's no distracting *incorrect* coloring):

```sh
# This is a single-line comment; see below for block comments, which don't work.
```

```sh
# A (multi-line) pipeline; see below for line-continuation.
# Note: Very little coloring here, but at least there's no *incorrect*
#       coloring.
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath E:\ -Recurse -Directory | 
  Where-Object { $_.FullName.Length -ge 95 -and $_.BaseName.Length -ge 44 } |
  Sort-Object -Descending { $_.FullName.Length } |
  Rename-Item -NewName { $_.BaseName.Substring(0, 10) + $_.Extension } -WhatIf
```

```sh
# Variable assignments, string literals.
# See below re strings ending in \"
$foo = 'bar none'            # single-quoted
$bar = "Honey,`nI'm $HOME"   # double-quoted
# double-quoted with escaped " - "" works; see below for `"
$baz = "There was 3"" of snow."

# *Simple* here-strings.
@'
This is a line.
Another line.
'@

@"
This is a line.
Another line.
"@

# Here-strings that have **embedded strings using the same quoting*,
# render *somewhat* broken, but at least subsequent statements
# aren't affected:
@'
This is an 'embedded single-quoted string'.
Another line.
'@

@"
This is an "embedded double-quoted string".
$HOME is where the heart is.
2 + 2 = $(2 + 2)
Another line.
"@
```

```sh
# Language statements, such as `foreach`
foreach ($i in 0..19 + 19..0) {
  ' ' * (19-$i) + 'o ' * $i
}

# ... or `switch` ("break" is a Bash keyword, so it's highlighted)
switch -Wildcard -File $someFile {
  '#*' { $_ }
  default { break }
}
```

```sh
# Line continuations (which are best avoided).
Get-ChildItem `
  -LiteralPath "C:\temp" `
  -Filter *.txt
```

```sh
# .NET method calls:

# in-line
[int]::Parse(' 42', [cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture)

# multi-line
[int]::Parse(
  ' 42', 
  [cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture
)
```

- What **DOESN'T work** (shows workarounds, where possible):

```sh
<# 
 a block 
 comment, notably one containing what are normally
 syntax elements, such as a "quoted string"
 Fortunately, block comments are rare in PowerShell code snippets on SO.
#>
```

```sh
# A double-quoted string ending \" is interpreted as
# an escaped ", so the string's end isn't recognized.
# Note how "Get-Date" on the next line is colored as if it were
# still part of the string.
# WORKAROUNDS:
#   * If feasible, use '...\', i.e. *single*-quoting instead.
#   * A \ at the end of a file path is often not necessary and can be omitted.
#   * Place a dummy comment with a single " at the end of the line,
#     to at least avoid impacting subsequent lines; you can precede
#     this dummy comment - #" - with enough whitespace so that it
#     is out of view by default (would only become visible with horizontal
#     scrolling.
Get-ChildItem "C:\temp\" -Filter *.txt
Get-Date
```

```sh
# Similarly, an unbalanced escaped `" inside "..." causes
# the true end of the string NOT to be recognized, as evidenced by 
# "of snow" not rendering as part of the string and "Get-Date"
# on the next line being considered part of a *new* string that 
# the " after "of snow" is considered to have started.
# WORKAROUND:
#   Use "" instead of `" to escape embedded " chars.
$baz = "There was 3`" of snow."
Get-Date
```

---

<sup>[1] That is, all code blocks then use SE's `default` highlighting, reflected in the HTML with an outer `<pre class="default s-code-block">` element; see the next footnote for how to inspect this, and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19820297/why-does-changing-the-sum-order-returns-a-different-result) for an example, which has competing [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) and [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) tags.</sup>

<sup>[2] You can determine what specific language was auto-detected for a given block by using ```` ```lang-powershell ```` and then inspecting the resulting HTML: `lang-powershell` is retained as the *outer* `class` value, but the first child element reveals what actual highlighting language is being used, such as PHP in this example:

`<pre class="lang-powershell s-code-block">`

`<code class="hljs language-php">...`</sup>

Comment: Re: XML + Powershell, I can understand adding highlighting to Powershell tags, with a caveat that [Makyen has explained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421016/enable-automatic-and-on-demand-syntax-highlighting-for-powershell-updated-for-h#comment931086_421016): if there are 2 or more tags with different language highlighting, then all will default to "default highlighting" instead, and each code block needs to be given highlighting hint.

Comment: Thanks, @AndrewT., I've updated the post to clarify; please check that I got this right; I'm assuming you're saying that if at least two tags that have mapped highlighting languages are present, _automatic detection_ kicks on for _each block_. Correct?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I observed from [this question with both 'java' and 'javascript' tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19820297/why-does-changing-the-sum-order-returns-a-different-result) where no code blocks on the answers are highlighted with either 'java' or 'javascript'.

Comment: There isn't any point in using syntax highlighting for any of these at the moment. For all practical purposes, syntax highlighting for the shell scripting languages is completely broken (e.g., what seems to be random highlight of variables names that happen to be some keyword in another context. Or weird highlighting of any kind of command line invocations (most scripts have them), with different options on the same level highlighted differently). With the current syntax highlighter, the syntax highlight for them ought to be turned off completely. And yes, this *is* configurable.

Comment: @PeterMortensen, syntax highlighting isn't about _perfection_, it's about whether it _de facto_ helps the human observer visualize parse the code. It comes down to whether the highlighting is more helpful than not. Notably, it's very important to highlight _comments_ as such, and something like `lang-bash` does that for PowerShell, while _often_ - but definitely not always - doing the right(-enough) thing in general. To me, that's indubitably preferable to having _no_ highlighting at all.

Comment: On the subject of load and priorities: Powershell-tagged questions are now more common than bash-tagged questions.

https://insights.stackoverflow.com/trends?tags=powershell%2Clisp%2Cperl%2Cbash%2Ccmd%2Cscheme%2Cgo%2Cjulia

Comment: Good to know, @Pxtl, thanks - and good to know about [insights.stackoverflow.com/trends](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/trends) in general.